# How to use Front-facing camera to take pictures on windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I've got two questions about how to access the camera on Windows Phone 8:

1. How can I access the front-facing camera to take pictures?
2. How can I access the flash/torch of main camera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [**article from MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) has an example of both accessing the front and back cameras, as well as accessing the flash, assuming your using C# (since you didn't specify). Here's a snippet under the **Creating the Capture Device** heading:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<Windows.Foundation.Size> SupportedResolutions = 
   PhotoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(CameraSensorLocation.Front);
Windows.Foundation.Size res = SupportedResolutions[0];
this.captureDevice = await PhotoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(CameraSensorLocation.Front, res);
```

For accessing the flash of the camera, here is a snippet under the **Specifying Camera Properties** heading:

```
cam.SetProperty(KnownCameraPhotoProperties.FlashMode, FlashState.On);
cam.SetProperty(KnownCameraGeneralProperties.PlayShutterSoundOnCapture, true);
cam.SetProperty(KnownCameraGeneralProperties.AutoFocusRange, AutoFocusRange.Infinity);
```

Hope this helps!